# Running concurrent powerline networks

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I currently have a pair of 200Mbps TP-Link powerline adapters delivering the Internet to my work station.

I would like to add another pair to the same power grid in order to send video from an HTPC to my television.

Will the two networks be able to coexist peacefully and without incident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like [several Powerline networks can exist simultaneously in same power circuit](http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?faqid=433).